# Как сделать выборку пустых ячеек в массиве 60х60?

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, поиск, матрицы

Всем привет!
Задумал сделать страничку для посетителей столовой, на страничке карта посадочных мест, примерно 60х60 (столы в 30 рядов, в каждом ряду по 60 мест).
Одно место - один квадратик.
Решил использовать map area, набросал простенькую базу данных, там храню координаты мест, которые посетитель выбрал (такое своеобразное бронирование), т.е. 4 числа.
Теперь встал вопрос, как посетителям запретить бронировать НЕсвободные места: показываю занятые места скриптом maphilight (подсветка), но чтобы не давать забронировать, нужен какой-то фильтр или что еще?

Comment: Укажите в тегах какой язык программирования или технологию вы используете, иначе ваш вопрос   может остаться не замеченным

Comment: база данных на MySql, вывод через php плюс js